# TYPO3 - Insert api medipim

Tags: api, typo3-8.7.x

I want to call products on a web page via the api of [Medipim](https://www.medipim.be/). I have never done this before and I have never worked with TYPO3.

Therefore two questions.

1. In which (`config`) file do I place the authentication (I have an ID and secret key) and what exactly does that code look like?
2. When I want to call up the products, how do I use this in the TYPO3 page environment? Do I have to choose a `html` page or can I just enter it in the TYPO3 editor on a page?

Documentation: [watch](https://platform.medipim.be/docs/api/v3/)

Answer (score 0):

You probably need an extension which converts the data you get from medipim to HTML. I Expect you get information as JSON, XML, or CSV.

As you won't publish your access code you probably will not use a javascript call from the browser to access the API, then you need some PHP.

Using PHP in TYPO3 is done in extensions. You should learn about building extensions in TYPO3. As a healper you might use the  TYPO3 extension "Extension Builder" (=EB). As you have no local records you only need the extension frame with just one plugin from the EB.

Depending on your usage (will an editor select products from Medipim (option A) or should the visitor be able to select products (option B)?) you need a plugin with an option to insert desired product identification for BackEnd editors or just an input mask.

you can configure your plugin with typoscript so an integrator can enter the authentification information just once.

For option A you need to enhance your plugin with a field for the product ids. 
keyword: flexform

for Option B you need a form.

Then you need to display the product information you get from the API. provide the returned data in variables and use Fluid templates to get a nice display.

Without any knowledge of TYPO3 this will be hard work and a lot to learn. The other possibility: hire an experienced TYPO3 developer and let him build this extension for you.